# Stop on specific div until it is scrolled to its end. (CSS/JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

How do I stop overall site scrolling on a specific div (which also needs scrolling), hold on there until it's fully scrolled down and then go on?

Example: http://melaniedaveid.com/ (blocks like About, Work etc)

Thanks

Comment: Why not have a look at their code and try something?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to bind on "scroll" window event and make your markup reflect the animation when reaching certain scrolling positions.

The full answer to your question is pretty big and actually is kinda the solution in itself.

Look into jQuery and CSS properties "position" (esp. fixed seems good for this matter), "scroll" (to control the scrollbars appearance") and "overflow" (to controll the scrollbox).

Comment: i studied the example carefully and noticed that they don't scroll the div itself, but let it be full height and then stick the 'title' div to scroll near it as long as needed. that slightly changes the task :)
thank you anyway for good advice!